# Emitir una señal para que un modal se muestre en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy trabajando en un modal que va a ser compartido por todas las pantallas que haga.

Este es el **loader.html**

```
<div *ngIf="loading" class="modal-backdrop" style="opacity: 0.7;">
  <div class="text-center spinner">
    <div class="spinner-border text-light" role="status" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;">
      <span class="sr-only">Cargando</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este es el **loader.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.sass']
})

export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() loading: boolean;
  public display: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log( this.loading );
  }
}
```

Lo implementé desde otro HTML simplemente llamando al selector
**otro.html**

```
<button (click)="swap()">Cambiar</button>
<app-loader [loading]='loading'><app-loader>
```

Mi archivo **otro.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-otro',
  templateUrl: './otro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./otro.component.sass']
})

export class OtroComponent implements OnInit {
 @Output() loading = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
 swapi = false;
 constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading.emit( false );
  }

  swap() {
    const emit = !this.swapi;
    this.swapi = !this.swapi;
    this.loading.emit( emit );
  }
}
```

Según yo con eso debería estar cambiando si se ve o no se ve mi loader. Cuando llega al `console.log()` del **loader.ts** me aparece que es de tipo EventEmmiter y tiene varios parámetros. ¿Cómo puedo recibir el parámetro que envié desde el otro componente?

---

> También acepto sugerencias de optimización, voy aprendiendo.

---

Answer (score 0):

Creo que para tu caso no haria falta el uso de `EventEmitter` ya que le puedes pasar directamenete el valor como parametro en el selector. Te sugiero una alternativa que cumple con tus propositos:

el complemento **loader.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.css']
})
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() loading:boolean=false;
  constructor() { }    
  ngOnChanges(){
    console.log('Loader msg',this.loading);
  }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

el **loader.html**

```
<div *ngIf="loading" class="modal-backdrop" style="opacity: 0.7;">
  <div class="text-center spinner">
    <div class="spinner-border text-light" role="status" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;">
      <span class="sr-only">Cargando</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

el complemento **otro.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-otro',
  templateUrl: './otro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./otro.component.sass']
})
export class OtroComponent implements OnInit {
  public loading:boolean;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {    
  }
  swap() {
    this.loading=!this.loading;
    console.log('other msg',this.loading);
  }
}
```

el **otro.html**

```
<button (click)="swap()">Cambiar</button>
<app-loader [loading]='loading'><app-loader>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.